# Refactor closure criteria to fix maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Tags: java, grails, groovy, closures, criteria

I've found the following piece of code in an application I have to maintain

```
 def addCriteriaClosure = { criteriaList ->
   criteriaList.inList('id', paketInstance.dateien.id)
 }
 def criteria = Datei.createCriteria()
 def result = criteria.list() {
   addCriteriaClosure.call(criteria)
 }
```

Sadly, this call results in the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
```

Fact is that `paketInstance.dateien` contains more then 1000 rows / items.
To avoid this error I've tried the following approach:

```
def addCriteriaClosure = { criteriaList ->
  paketInstance.dateien.asList().collate(999).each {
    criteriaList.inList('id', paketInstance.dateien.asList().collate(999).id)
  }
}
```

but this results in this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

I know that the solution is to use the `collate(999)` operation, but I don't know how to combine it with the initial approach to get the expected result.

**Edit #1**

Unfortunatly **I can not** edit this part of the implementation:

```
 def criteria = [Type].createCriteria()
 def result = criteria.list() {
   addCriteriaClosure.call(criteria)
 }
```

Where the concrete type gets passed in to the method.
I only can edit the definition of the `addCriteriaClosure` 
For example:

```
 def addCriteriaClosure = { criteriaList ->
   criteriaList.inList('id', paketInstance.dateien.id)
 }
```

**Edit #2**

When I design my criteria closure like following

```
def l = paketInstance.dateien.id.toList().collate(999)
        def addCriteriaClosure = { criteriaList ->

            l.each {
                a -> criteriaList.inList("id", a.toList())
            }
        }
```

Hibernate creates an SQL-Statement which splits the lists into to seperate `in` WHERE clauses. But the problem is that these two clauses are linked with an `AND`. To get the right result I need the `OR` for the two lists, not the `AND` in the generated sql

produced SQL:

```
 select this_.id as id51_0_, this_.version as version51_0_, this_.aktualisiert_am as aktualis3_51_0_, this_.name as name51_0_, this_.nummer as nummer51_0_, this_.pfad as pfad51_0_, this_.status as status51_0_, this_.typ as typ51_0_ from datei this_ where this_.id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?....)  and this_.id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?....)
```

So Instead of `and this_.id` in I need `or this_.id in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

```
def collatedFileList = paketInstance.dateien.id.toList().collate(999)
        def addCriteriaClosure = { criteriaList ->
            criteriaList.or {
                collatedFileList.each {
                    l -> criteriaList.inList("id", l.toList())
                }
            }
        }
```

1. Resolves the problem I had to face
2. Learned a lot about the Closure / Criteria thing

Answer (score 1):

Try an approach like this instead:

```
def manyThingsToFind = [...list of more than 1000 things...]
def clauseLimit = 999
def results = YourDomainObject.createCriteria().listDistinct {
  or {
    manyThingsToFind.collate(clauseLimit)?.each { collatedList ->
      'in'("fieldToMatch", collatedList)
    }
  }
}
```

You can break the actual criteria out into a closure if you want, as you have done already.

Comment: Thanks. But as I can't break the whole implementation I need to get just the closure. Because in the further process its used like `if (addCriteriaClosure) { addCriteriaClosure.call(criteria) }` Thats why I can just define the closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the list of IDs to have no more than 999 items, you should use

```
def idList = paketInstance.dateien.asList().id[0..<999]
```

### Aside

Throwing away some of the IDs to be compared just because Oracle doesn't allow more than 1000 items in an `in` predicate does not seem like a good solution. Assuming this list of IDs is retrieved from the database, you should be able to use a subquery/join to perform the comparison instead.

Comment: Sorry for missing information: Sure I would like to display all data. But this software seems to use GORM or Hibernate. So Im not able to write my own SQL queries. If I use the first approach I've posted I get the corresponding Oracle exception. So I would like to achive to get all Information without getting an exception...